# what are Mandatory settings for acc register in pjsip

Tags: android

In my code i set the below settings to add one account to pjsip , in this after 60sec timeout account not re-registering, if any body knows tell me.In my case re-registeration is not happening , what the problem ?

```
              int[] accId = new int[1];
        accId[0] = 1;

        pjsua_acc_config cfg = new pjsua_acc_config();
        pjsua.acc_config_default(cfg);
        csipsimple_acc_config css_cfg = new csipsimple_acc_config();
        pjsua.csipsimple_acc_config_default(css_cfg);

        cfg.setPriority(100);
        cfg.setId(pjsua.pj_str_copy("sip:" + sipUser + "@" + sipServer));
        cfg.setReg_uri(pjsua.pj_str_copy("sip:" + sipServer)); 
                    cfg.setReg_timeout(60);
        cfg.setCred_count(1);

        cfg.setUse_rfc5626(pjsuaConstants.PJ_TRUE);
        cfg.setReg_delay_before_refresh(0);
        cfg.setPublish_enabled(0);

        pjsua_transport_config rtpCfg = cfg.getRtp_cfg();
         rtpCfg.setPort(5060);//5060 //4000



        pjsip_cred_info cred_info = cfg.getCred_info();
        cred_info.setRealm(pjsua.pj_str_copy(sipServer));
        cred_info.setScheme(pjsua.pj_str_copy("Digest"));
        cred_info.setUsername(pjsua.pj_str_copy(sipUser));
         cred_info.setData_type(pjsip_cred_data_type.
                     PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD.swigValue());
        cred_info.setData(pjsua.pj_str_copy(password));
        cfg.setKa_interval(40);

        pjsua.csipsimple_set_acc_user_data(cfg, css_cfg);
        status = pjsua.acc_add(cfg, pjsuaConstants.PJ_FALSE, accId);


        if (status == pjsuaConstants.PJ_SUCCESS) {
            status = pjsua.acc_set_online_status(accId[0], 1);
            Log.i("Setting online status to online", "---online--"
                                +status);
        } else {
            Log.i("Not success", "---un success--" + status);
```

Comment: does this code successfully register the account the first time?

Comment: yes, but re-registeration is not working

Comment: in the above code registeration is working properly but after timeout sipserver not re-registering the account,that is problem if anybody knows tell me.

Comment: I have the same code and my code fails on the `pjsua.csipsimple_set_acc_user_data(cfg, css_cfg);` line. I get a Fatal Error. Did you do something before this method?